# How to show a window in Qt and deleting it as soon as it's closed?

Tags: qt, qdialog

As a very simple example, I want to show a dialog in Qt when I press a button. The usual pattern for this (in the application I'm currently working on) seems to be as follows:

```
class MainWindow {
  ...
private slots:
  buttonClicked();
  ...
private:
  ChildWindow * childWindow;
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget * parent) : QWidget(parent) {
  ...
  childWindow = new ChildWindow(this);
  ...
}

MainWindow::buttonClicked() {
  childWindow.show();
}
```

Coming from .NET and Windows Forms (and because I don't need access to that object from elsewhere in the class) the following pattern is more familiar to me:

```
button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ChildWindow f = new ChildWindow();
  f.Show();
}
```

The local variable means I don't have yet another instance field and also that the window won't linger around in memory for much longer than necessary. A direct translation of that to C++ would be a bit ugly because no one would clear up afterwards. I tried the following things:

1. `shared_ptr`. No luck, the window is `delete`d as soon as the method ends which means the new window appears for a split second and vanishes again. Not so good.
2. `exec()` instead of `show()`. This would work for modal dialogs, but documentation seemed to imply that it also stops the event loop and that you should call `QApplication::processEvents()` regularly if it still needs to be updated. I understand little enough here but I guess it's not too nice either.
3. `deleteLater()`. Sadly, just showing a window doesn't block `deleteLater` so it vanishes as soon as it appears.

Is there a nice option to just clean up after the window when I close it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
childWindow->setAttribute( Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose );
```

Also note that calling `exec()` will block execution of the calling event loop, but will spawn its own event loop, so no calls to `processEvents()` should be necessary.

Comment: I couldn't find that advice for `exec` again anywhere in the docs, could be that it just was on some random blog of dubious value. And thanks for the attribute. I've searched for at least an hour (+build time for the experiments) until I stumbled on the idea to just connect the `finished` signal (which wasn't optimal but sufficient for my purpose).

Comment: It's actually documented quite clearly in this .cpp file http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/gui/dialogs/qdialog.cpp#line562 ;)

Comment: I was referring to what I wrote in the question regarding `processEvents`. That `exec` stops the parent event loop is fairly obvious, because it's blocking; also that it has to create a new one for the dialog.

Answer (score 3):

You can connect the `finished()` signal of th dialog to its `deleteLater` slot:

```
ChildWindow * d = new ChildWindow(this);
connect(d, SIGNAL(finished(int)), d, SLOT(deleteLater()));
d->show();
```

This way it will be `delete`d as soon as you close the dialog.

Comment: Note: This works in the case where no dialog result is needed. If you still need the argument from `finished()` then I don't know what happens. But for my problem here that was enough.