# QMainWindow closes right after show()

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am new to Qt (use Objective-C mostly) so I am stuck with probably noob issue. From the `QDialog` window I try to open `QMainWindow` like this:

```
this->close();
SQLWindow window;
window.receivePath(path); //Path for the .sqlite file
window.show()
```

`QDialog` closes and for millisecond I see a glimpse of a new window, but it closes too. Below is `QMainWindow` part:

```
SQLWindow::SQLWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::SQLWindow) 
{ 
    ui->setupUi(this); 
    this->initialSetup(); 
} 

SQLWindow::~SQLWindow() 
{ 
    delete ui; 
} 

void SQLWindow::initialSetup() 
{ 
    ui->tableView->setSortingEnabled(true); 
    ui->tableView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers); 
} 

void SQLWindow::receivePath(QString path) 
{ 
   this->openDatabase(path); 
} 

void SQLWindow::openDatabase(QString path) 
{
    //Opening database just fine
}
```

Comment: I expect the problem is in a dialog application when the dialog closes so does the application. Also your window is a local variable which will no longer exist when the scope ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your window is a local variable it is destroyed at the end of the function and hence the destructor closes it.
What you could do is create the `SQLWindow` on the heap with `new SQLWindow` and e.g. use the `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15814799/2128694).

Alternatively, a better design might be to create both the dialog and the window as local variables of the `main` function and let the main function pass the path from the dialog to the `SQLWindow`, then you need no `new`.

Comment: Your answer sounds extremely logical and useful, but I need time to check if it works (cause I am not really good at Qt) :P

Comment: Yes, thats it. Thank you very much for answer :3